# Pandas Keyerror when specifying loc row labels using a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe [Positive Samples Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN5jZ.png) loaded from a txt file using pandas

This positive samples dataframe has a column called Gene Set, which is basically a list of genes. When I run `postive_samples["Gene Set"]`  I get the following output

> > `['YAL004W', 'YLL024C'] ['YAL005C', 'YLL024C'] ['YAL005C', 'YMR006C'] ['YAL005C', 'YOL090W'] ['YAL009W', 'YBR074W'] ['YAL009W', 'YER162C'] ['YAL009W', 'YHL024W'] ['YAL009W', 'YJL187C'] ['YAL009W', 'YKR003W']`

I also have another dataframe called  `new_expression_df` [New Expression Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe8W0.png), which has `positive_samples["Gene Set"]` column as its index.

So What i am trying to do is get the values which are stored in postive_samples["Gene Set"] as they are and locate them using loc in the new_expression_df index using a loop.

```
samples_column_list= ["GSM144760","GSM144761","GSM144762","GSM144763","GSM144764"]

for gene_class_column in postive_samples[['Gene Set']]:
  #Select column contents by column name using [] operator
    geneSeriesObj = postive_samples[gene_class_column]
    gene_pairs = geneSeriesObj.values

#get gene pairs and locate their expression in the given samples    
for gene_pair in gene_pairs:
  new_expression_df.loc[gene_pair,samples_column_list]
```

I am getting a key Error at the beginning of the iteration when I try to do this using a loop, ideally I want to get each gene set as a list, locate its values in another data frame using its index.

But, when I plug in each set like below without using a loop it works just fine for the same values I get a Key Error for, so what am I doing wrong here?

```
new_expression_df.loc[['YAL002W','YBL001C'],samples_column_list]
```

I want to put the row  argument of the loc function dynamically from another data frame column values which are stored in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Can you print `gene_pairs` just before the second for loop?

Comment: when I print gene_pairs I get the same output highlighted above, like below on each iteration. So each iteration outputs one list

['YAL004W', 'YLL024C']
['YAL005C', 'YLL024C']
['YAL005C', 'YMR006C']
['YAL005C', 'YOL090W']
['YAL009W', 'YBR074W']
['YAL009W', 'YER162C']
['YAL009W', 'YHL024W']
['YAL009W', 'YJL187C']
['YAL009W', 'YKR003W']

Comment: Can you tell me the output of the following- `for gene_pair in gene_pairs: print(gene_pair) new_expression_df.loc[gene_pair,samples_column_list]`

Comment: what that does is, it prints each pair.  ['YAL004W', 'YLL024C'] is one output of print(gene_pair). A gene pair is the 2 elements of the array/list I gave above. So if I put it in a loop it outputs all the other pairs like I commented above but what I want to do is, put each output iteration in the loc function and execute it without getting the key error

Comment: Try using .at instead of .loc. Also can you pass the value to print method? `for gene_pair in gene_pairs:
  print(new_expression_df.loc[gene_pair,samples_column_list])`

Comment: I think .loc is better compared to .at, since I am trying to return values based on more than one row and column, but I gave it a shot though and its giving me a type error if I use .at because I am giving it a list  The output is still the same, I get the key error even when I wrap that in a print statement. What I am wondering is how is it having a key error when using a loop but not having any errors when I plug all the values manually into the .loc function? It does not make any sense ‍♂️. I am literally plugging in the same values with or without the loop